# how to check top, right, left values of canvas in javascript

Tags: javascript

I draw a square and Area.Now I just check bottom for canvas square. Ex: when a square move to top(if the top == square then stopped)...

```
this.hitBottom=function()
    {
        var rbottom=myGameArea.canvas.height-this.height;
        if(this.y > rbottom)
        {
            this.y=rbottom;
            //this.gravitySpeed=0;
        }
    }
```

I want to check top, right, left of canvas. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can check values of any attributes with jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Or you can get the CSS styles with jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your x and y are the lower left corner.

```
this.hitBottom = function() {
  var rbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
  if (this.y > rbottom) {
    this.y = rbottom;
    //this.gravitySpeed=0;
  }
}
this.hitTop = function() {
  if (this.y - this.height < 0) {
    this.y = this.height;
    //this.gravitySpeed=0;
  }
}
this.hitLeft = function() {
  if (this.x < 0) {
    this.x = 0;
    //this.gravitySpeed=0;
  }
}
this.hitRight = function() {
  if (this.x > myGameArea.canvas.width - this.width) {
    this.x = myGameArea.canvas.width - this.width;
    //this.gravitySpeed=0;
  }
}
```